# gradle liquibase plugin, gradle update succeeds, however no changes are applied

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I came across this issue in attempting creating a gradle database centric project for managing all my db migrations.  I am leveraging 1.2.1 of the plugin and believe I have configured everything properly, however, my changesets aren't applied even though there are no rows in the databasechangelog and the update status reports success shown below (output from gradle update --debug).

21:55:27.248 **[ERROR] [system.err]** INFO 2/26/16 9:55 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
21:55:27.452 [ERROR] [system.err] Liquibase Update Successful

As you can see gradle or liquibase isn't happy about something and I'm not entirely sure how to get at the offending error.  The error is first encountered during the execution of the liquibase-plugin see below:

21:55:20.078 **[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project]** liquibase-plugin: Running 'liquibase --logLevel=debug --changeLogFile=myschema/changelog.groovy --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MYDB --username=myschema --password=mypass update'
21:55:20.722 **[ERROR] [system.err]**  DEBUG 2/26/16 9:55 PM: liquibase: Connected to MYSCHEMA@jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MYDB
21:55:20.722 [ERROR] [system.err] DEBUG 2/26/16 9:55 PM: liquibase: Connected to MYSCHEMA@jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MYDB
21:55:20.722 [ERROR] [system.err] DEBUG 2/26/16 9:55 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
21:55:20.879 [ERROR] [system.err] DEBUG 2/26/16 9:55 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK

Can I bubble up the system.err to something I can physically see either in gradle or within liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

Gotta love syntax errors.  Change logs had two syntax errors one of which was a result from moving from grails.  Groovy DSL for liquibase is different in Grails then in the gradle liquibase plugin and changelogs are slightly different formats.  After fixing the syntax errors it runs without issues.